# Custom syntax highlight color settings are reset/overridden on next launch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have no extensions at the moment, yet VS2019 keeps forcing the following purple/golden colors on syntax every launch:

[image: VS2019]

If I go to Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors and click on "Use Defaults" I get the correct (blue) theme again. However, if I restart VS, it's broken again.

I run VS2017 on the same machine and that works correctly.

Am I missing a setting somewhere or is this a bug in VS2019? I've already reinstalled it a few times and cleared out all settings I could find in registry and disk, but the problem remains.

As a side note, **Import and Export Settings...** isn't working correctly either. If I try **Reset all settings** I can only click one time **Next** and then after the following **Next** the window disappears (same with **Import selected environment settings**).

Comment: This is syntax coloring, not an overal color scheme or theme

Comment: Correct, clarified the text :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This annoying problem existed in RC version, too. I like syntax coloring, but this scheme is way too distracting for me.

Up to now, the only way I could find was to set the colors by myself. They won't change across restarts that way, but it is a pain in the neck to modify all of them one by one.

Luckily (for you and me) your post prompted me to investigate further, and I've found a little "gem" hidden among the settings.

**Go to the Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced tab. There is a setting called "Classifications, Use enhanced colors for C# and Basic" and just turn it off.**

I hereby would like thank to the people who thought of the "feature" in the first place and make it default in the second place.

If I were British, I wouldn't hesitate a second to show them a reverse victory sign with both of my hands. >:(

Cheers.

Comment: Great, that was it indeed, worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: You are quite welcome. And, I thank you to remind me to look at this issue closely. At last, we both got rid of this scheme we don't like. :)

Answer (score 6):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced (SCROLL DOWN)
Editor Color Scheme (Drop Down Menu) choose Visual Studio 2019.

---

#### Tools

[image]

---

#### Options

[image]

---

#### Text Editor

[image]

---

#### C# -> Advanced (Scroll Down)

[image]

Comment: This is the correct way to do in newer versions. And it requires a restart.

Comment: In the newest Visual Studio 2022, you need to select Color Scheme to **Visual Studio 2017**!

Answer (score 1):

These new colors are default colors.

To get old default colors -> Go to Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced and uncheck "use enhanced colors for C# and Basic"